# Understanding X/Understanding *of* X: What's the distinction?

Tags: prepositions, gerunds, differences

Say we have two sentences that use *understanding* as a gerund:

> Understanding how to open this door is crucial in the event of an emergency.
>
> My understanding **of** physics is woefully inadequate.

What is the distinction between these two that calls for the inclusion of *of* in the second sentence but not in the first?

(I have an inkling that it's got something to do with the determiner, but I can't quite pin it down.)

Answer (score 3):

In the first sentence, *understanding* is a verb, used in its most common sense.

In the second one it's a mass noun. ([OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/understanding)) In this sense of the noun *understanding*, *of* would be required. Just like it would be in *my grasp/comprehension/love/hate of physics...*

For future reference, in cases where replacing *understanding* with *to understand* doesn't make any sense at all, it's a noun.

Comment: You might want to say that it's not an ordinary verb but a gerund, and hence can often be substituted by the to-infinitive.